# PHP I can "cat" text file to screen but not lp1

Tags: php, apache, ubuntu, linux-mint

I have a simple text file "receipt.txt" that I want to send to my 58mm pos printer.  I can "cat" the file to the terminal display and I can run the following command from my web page and it all works great.

```
echo exec('cat /var/www/html/ricksregister/register/receipt.txt');
var_dump($output);
```

But it wont print to lp1.

```
echo exec('cat /var/www/html/ricksregister/register/receipt.txt >> /dev/usb/lp1', $output);
var_dump($output);
```

I wonder about permissions but not exactly sure what they should be.  I'm running linux mint with username and group of rick.  I have tried

```
chown -R rick:rick register
chmod -R 777 register
```

and

```
chown -R root:rick register
chmod -R 777 register
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Please correct your answer. First code snippet is incorrect, 2nd misses slashes.

Comment: im new at this, so thats my problem, I don't know what wrong with the code snippet, and I don't know which slashes are missing.  That's why I posted the question.  Oh and by the way, this is a question and not an answer

Comment: So you cant see any difference between the first code snippet's path and in the 2nd one? Nor that you clearly don't close your exec function? Or that you have `', $output);` twice at the end of your 2nd snippet?

Comment: Seriously, i have been beating my head on this one for two days.  I have tried to understand the php manual on exec, but is a bit foggy to me.  I have searched thru Google and Ubuntu and everywhere I can think of.  I know i'm close

Comment: oh oh I see the missing slash, i'll try it now

Comment: My apologies, I don't know what happened there, Mr fat finger.  It should be corrected now.  It was correct in my code, so I still have the same question

Comment: This looks like a *nix problem.  We know that it is not perms on the file, so probably it's the user running apache.  Take a look at the lp1 device ownership.  What is the group?  What is the user running apache?  Make sure that user is a member of the group owning the lp1 device.

Comment: It's also worth noting that this permissions stuff is managed for you by CUPS or lpr, and since those systems have better overall management, with things like page queues, you should probably use those instead.  Here's some info on using lpr:  https://www.computerhope.com/unix/ulpr.htm

Comment: I've deleted my post as it is not relevent to send it to a printer, I seem to have missed that.